# Does bs4 retrieve the entire webpage, even if it requires physically scrolling through to get all elements?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am very new to coding, and I am learning by doing in Python, also I apologize if I break any rules with this post.

My question is, as stated in the headline, can i get bs4 to download an entire webpage, despite it requiring physically scrolling through to load all elements?

I have found out, I can do it in Java, but i would like to keep it to Python, as I am still very new to coding, and would like to focus on one language at the time.

The webpage in question is this one: "https://www.ejendomstorvet.dk/investering/vestjylland/boligudlejning"

I have uploaded an example of the html code here, where you can see the elements in question:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDmr0.jpg

I am not asking for a specific solution here, just some pointers, to which functionalities in bs4 I should use to do this, or alternatively, if i need to do it through another add-in program?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BS4 uploads only HTML code from the entered URL. It does not get all pages from the site (but it certainly can do that if you show URLs where should it go, but that is more Python work, than BS4). And that also means that BS4 does not scrap JavaScript from pages. So if there is any content which is loaded by JavaScript/Ajax - BS4 can't deal with it. So if you in your question mean - if BS4 can parse simple long HTML page with a lot of elements - answer is **Yes**, but if you mean if it can parse downloadable elements from that page - answer is **No**.

P.S. If you need to scrap some JS elements from any page - you can use on [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) or if you want to get a full control on JS on any page, but much more complicated - [Selenium](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/introduction-to-web-scraping-using-selenium-7ec377a8cf72).

Comment: Thank you, i will probably be looking into using scrapy or selenium.